# How to set the utf-8 for the code file (.pl) in swi-prolog desktop

Tags: swi-prolog

I'm trying to develeop for frequently answered questions (faq) about something with using swi-prolog. I use swi-prolog for desktop (AMD64, Multi-threaded, version 8.2.3).
The questions and the answers in the faq are written in the native language of Turkey. When I run the code file (k-base.pl and user.pl) the Turkish characters /like ş-ğ-ü-ö/ look corrupt.
I wonder if there's any syntax for the code file for utf-8 or any settings in swi-prolog desktop for this language problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to set the **prolog flag** called [`encoding`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags#flag:encoding).

> Default encoding used for opening files in text mode. The initial value > is deduced from the environment. See [encoding](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=encoding) for details.

**Read** it with [`current_prolog_flag/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_prolog_flag/2)

```
?- 
current_prolog_flag(encoding,X).
X = utf8.
```

**Set** it with [`set_prolog_flag/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=set_prolog_flag/2)

The documentation says that the value of that flag is read from the environment on program start.

That should be the environment variable `LANG` (at least on POSIX systems. More on on this variable for example in the [GNU gettext manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html)). In the shell:

```
# bash code

$ echo $LANG
en_GB.UTF-8
```

so you may want to check whether that environment variable influences `swipl`.

For example, start `swipl` with:

```
# bash code

$ LANG=en_GB.ASCII swipl
```

then:

```
?- 
current_prolog_flag(encoding,X).
X = iso_latin_1.
```

But `swipl` has some trouble with the usual codes:

```
# bash code

$ LANG=en_GB.ISO-8859-1 swipl
```

Then:

```
?- 
current_prolog_flag(encoding,X).
X = text.
```

What the dickens is this? The page on [encoding](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=encoding) lists the valid encoding keys, and `ISO-8859-1` is not one of them.

> *iso_latin_1*: 8-bit encoding supporting many Western languages.
> This causes the stream to be read and written fully untranslated.

This means a byte is just extended into a 2-byte (or larger) internal Unicode code points (although there should be some filtering?; not everything in *ISO-8859-1* maps to a valid Unicode code point).

> *text*: C library default locale encoding for text files. Files are
> read and written using the C library functions mbrtowc() and
> wcrtomb(). This may be the same as one of the other locales, notably
> it may be the same as iso_latin_1 for Western languages and utf8
> in a UTF-8 context.

Not sure how to interprete this.

Anyway, to set the environment variable in the bash shell:

```
# bash code

$ export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
$ swipl
```

**Alternatively** you can load the source with an option that specifies the encoding to expect:

[`load_files/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=load_files/2) with the option `encoding`:

```
?- 
load_files([foo],[encoding(utf8)]).
```

## A test

I just tested on my system with an UTF-8 file, with everything set to default:

```
# bash code

$ echo $LANG
en_GB.UTF-8

$ file citation.pl 
citation.pl: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

**Code**

```
citation :-
   писатель(1,Author),
   цитирование(1,Citation),
   format("Author: ~s~nCitation: ~s~n",[Author,Citation]).

% Facts!

писатель(1,"Р.П.Уоррен").
цитирование(1,"Ты должна сделать добро из зла, потому что его больше не из чего сделать.").
```

And thus:

```
?- 
[citation].
true.

?- 
citation.
Author: Р.П.Уоррен
Citation: Ты должна сделать добро из зла, потому что его больше не из чего сделать.
true.
```

Load failure:

```
?- 
load_files([citation],[encoding(ascii)]).
ERROR: citation.pl:2:4: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: citation.pl:8:2: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: citation.pl:9:2: Syntax error: illegal_character
Warning: citation.pl:10:
Warning:    'citation.pl':10:0: non-ASCII character
true.
```

Load failure:

```
?- 
load_files([citation],[encoding(iso_latin_1)]).
ERROR: citation.pl:2:4: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: citation.pl:8:2: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: citation.pl:9:2: Syntax error: illegal_character
true.
```

Success:

```
?- 
load_files([citation],[encoding(utf8)]).
true.
```

Answer (score 2):

For SWI-Prolog, there is `init.pl` file, you could set the `encoding` flag in that files.

Open swipl-win.exe -> Settings -> User init file..., SWI-Prolog will prompt you to create a `init.pl` file. In my computer, it is `C:\Users\Chansey\AppData\Roaming\swi-prolog\init.pl`.

Copy the following code to that file :

```
:- set_prolog_flag(encoding, utf8).
```

Restart `swipl-win.exe` or `swipl.exe`, you can load utf-8 encoding file by default.

Comment: This is the right answer; if the `init.pl` file doesn't exist on that path, just create it.